# Why flexbox equal and bootstrap(row-eq-height) column height doesn't work?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I've tried both ways to solve my problem(row-eq-height), but nothing happens, whatever I do.
I have three columns like this (.regytpe). I know that flex-container comes with several default settings, and maybe I override that in somewhere the code.

```
<a href="felreg.php?p=ceg">
    <div class="register_selector">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-12 col-lg-4 col-xs-12">
          <div id="cegreg-hover" class="regtype">
           <div class="regdiv text-center">
            <div class="regdiv-heading">
             <h1 id="cegvagyok" class="robotoBold">CÉG VAGYOK</h1>
            </div>
          <div class="regdiv-body">
           <img src="../img/ceg-ikon-idle.svg" class="img-responsive cegreg" />
         </div>
        <div class="regdiv-footer">
        <p class="caviarBold">REGISZTRÁLOK</p>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</a> ...

 <style>
  .register_selector{
   display: -ms-flex;
   display: -webkit-flex;
   display: flex;
   max-width: 1330px;
   height: 430px;
   position: absolute;
   margin: auto;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   border-radius: 3px;
   margin-top: 350px;
  }

  .regtype{
   display: table;
   margin: 0 auto;
   color: #ffffff;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
   -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
   transition: 0.5s;
   padding: 0 5px;
  }
 </style>
```

Comment: The equal column trick using flexbox needs to be applied to the immediate parent of the columns, i.e. on the `.row` element, not on `.register_selector`.

Comment: Yes, I did like this.  <div class="row row-eq-height">

Comment: I overrode the display in the children div with display: table.

Comment: You need to provide a minimal working code snippet reproducing the issue you have, so we get a clear picture of what doesn't work